# Show that the image of $T:l^{\infty}\to l^{\infty}$, $(x_n)_n \mapsto \Big(\frac{x_n}{n}\Big)_n$ is not closed in $l^{\infty}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Denote the set of all bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ by $l^{\infty}$, endowed with the sup norm $\lVert \rVert _{\infty}$. Define a map $T:l^{\infty} \to l^{\infty}$ as follows:

$$(x_n)_n \mapsto \Big(\frac{x_n}{n}\Big)_n.$$

Then the question is:

> Show that the image of $l^{\infty}$ under $T$ is not a closed set in $l^{\infty}$.

***My attempts:***

As it is enough to show the existence of a sequence $(t_n)$ of bounded sequences from $T(l^{\infty})$ which converges to a sequence outside of it, I first considered the constant sequence $$(1,1, \ldots, 1, \ldots) = t_0$$ $(\notin T(l^{\infty}))$ and tried to look for a sequence $(t_n)$ of sequences in $T(l^{\infty})$ which goes to it. The following are two (failed) attempts to construct such a sequence.

First I thought the sequences $$t_n = (1,1,\ldots,1,\frac{1}{(n+1)^2},\frac{1}{(n+2)^2},\ldots)$$ would work. But they didn't, because 
$$\lVert t_n-t_0\rVert_{\infty} = \sup_{k\geq n}\Big|1-\frac{1}{k^2}\Big|=1 \nrightarrow 0$$  as $n\to \infty$ and thus $(t_n) \nrightarrow t_0$.

Also I thought about the sequences $$t_n = (1,1,\ldots,1,1+\frac{1}{n+1},1+\frac{1}{n+2},\ldots,1+\frac{1}{n+m},\ldots).$$ In this case $(t_n) \to t_0$ as $n \to \infty$, but none of the $t_n$'s is an element of $T(l^{\infty})$. So this sequence also is of no use.

Any help? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: $t_0$ will not work because $B(t_0,1/2)$ has empty intersection with $T(l^\infty)$.

Comment: Hi Diego, I'd like to know what did I do incorrectly below if your statement is the case? If it's wrong, I want to delete it!

Comment: $1-\frac{m}{m+1}<1-\frac{m}{m+2}<...$

Comment: Ahhhh! Crap!! I thought I had it too... I'll delete it. Nice answer below by the way.

Comment: The idea behind Diego's example is the following: the range of $T$ contains the finitely supported sequences and is contained in $c_0$. It follows that the closure of the range of $T$ is $c_0$. And not every $c_0$ sequence is in the range of $T$, so it is not closed.

Comment: @julien : What do you mean by a "finitely supported sequence"? And what is your $c_0$?

Comment: Finitely supported: finitely many nonzero terms. $c_0$: sequences which tend to $0$. The former are dense in the latter. All this in $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @julien : Oh, thanks a ton for this simple explanation!! My understanding of this question would've been really incomplete without it. :D

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $t_0=(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\ldots)$ and $t_m=(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}},0,0,\ldots)$. Clearly $t_m\rightarrow t_0$, $t_m$ is in the image of $T$ and $t_0$ is not in the image of $T$.

Comment: Oh, that's much better than my example, +1.

Comment: Thanks for the really nice example, +1. :-)

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $t_0=(\frac {1}{\sqrt{n}})_n$.  This too is not in the image of $T$, since its preimage is $(\sqrt{n})_n$.  Now define $t_m=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}},\frac{\sqrt{m}}{m+1},\frac{\sqrt{m}}{m+2},\ldots)$, the image of $(\sqrt{1},\sqrt{2},\ldots,\sqrt{m},\sqrt{m},\sqrt{m},\ldots)$.  But now $\|t_m-t_0\|_\infty=\sup_{n> m}\{|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\sqrt{m}}{n}|\}=\sup_{n> m}\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}-1|\}<\frac{1}{m}$, because $0<|\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}-1|<1$

Comment: Answers should be constructive and should not add opinions that might make OPs feel degraded because they may not have understood something. I believe you got a downvote because of this and may want to update your answer. Regards